# variable not resolved inside a manual FTP session

Tags: bash, ftp

I am writing a bash/expect script that ssh to a linux box, fetches its serial number(eg S1234) then starts an ftp session to a licence server(unix box) and tries to download a license for that serial number (e.g. S1234.tar).

To eliminate any scripty issues, I tried the procedure manually:

1. telnet to linix box ====> Ok
2. MYSERIAL="$(print serial command).tar"   ====> Ok
3. echo $MYSERIAL  ====> Ok output is S1234.tar
4. ftp xx.xx.xx.xx =====> ftp license server Ok
5. get $MYSERIAL  =====> NOK, I get:

```
ftp> get $MYSERIAL  
local: $MYSERIAL  remote: $MYSERIAL  
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
550 Failed to open file.
ftp>
```

The variable `$MYSERIAL` is not resolved as S1234.tar inside the ftp session.

Anyone knows why it is the case?

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not passed/exported to the FTP program and I don't know if such a program exists that supports shell-style variables.

A common solution is to use a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) to pass the evaluated variable among other commands to the FTP programm, such as:

```bash
myserial=S1234.tar

ftp -n xx.xx.xx.xx <<-EOF
    user theuser thepassword
    get "$myserial"
    bye
EOF
```

<sub>(Note: Indentation is done using the tab character, if you don't need indentation, remove the `-` from `EOF`)</sub>

Or simpler with `curl` or `wget`:

```
curl -o "$myserial" "ftp://theuser:thepassword@xx.xx.xx.xx/$myserial"
curl -o "$myserial" xx.xx.xx.xx/"$myserial"
wget -nv xx.xx.xx.xx/"$myserial"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the ftp method and it worked for me.